# Entries in Area51 recent activity should display the full question title

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, area-51, recent-activity

Currently the recent activity only shows the proposal in which on-/off-topic votes were received, it doesn't directly show what question in that proposal received those votes (but it links directly to the specific question).

It would be much clearer if the question title would also be displayed in that view, just like it is displayed in the listing next to the reputation graph in the profile.

Comment: can you please clarify the issue? Are you looking at "/users/recent/587" or "/users/587?tab=activity"? Which type of activity is not showing the full question title?

I noticed one problem that I'll fix in a sec: On the activity tab of the user page, the title of the question you commented on isn't displayed. Is this the same problem you're reporting? Thanks.

Comment: @emmett: I was thinking about `/users/recent/587?tab=reputation`. There it says, for example, something got voted on in "Mathematics". I think it would be much more useful if it said the votes were for question "Mathematics: Where can I get math coaching for my child?".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is fixed now. Thanks @sth.