# Reputation from referral not showing up on my recent activity page

Tags: bug, status-completed, reputation, area-51

Looking at my Area 51 reputation report I see the following:

```
3       969 (5)
23       57 (5) **
2       968 (5)
2      1271 (5)
```

I'm assuming that the vote type of "23" is a referral.

However, looking at my recent activity page (http://area51.stackexchange.com/users/recent/87?Tab=Reputation&StartDate=2010-06-15&EndDate=2010-06-15) I only see:

[image]
<sub>(source: [free-online.co.uk](http://www.forman.free-online.co.uk/images/no-referral.png))</sub>

There's also a bug with the display of the last hyper link which may be related to [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53202/entries-in-area51-recent-activity-should-display-the-full-question-title)

Comment: It doesn't even show you reputation from people following or committing to your proposal (never did). I was waiting for someone to report it because they must already hate me due to the many posts I make...

Comment: @Juan - I've not proposed a site, so I wouldn't have spotted that ;)

Comment: We'll work on adding reputation gained from referrals to the recent activity page. But in the meantime, the display bug should be fixed now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is now working. I can see the rep from referrals (and pitifully low it is too).